# update query with NOLOCK

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query

```
update dbo.tbhints (NOLOCK) set off=12 where application =15
```

But this is giving me the below error

> Incorrect syntax near '('.'

Comment: possibly you are looking for https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90811/how-to-update-a-very-large-table-without-locking-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

`NOLOCK` can be used in `SQL Server`. Following is the equivalent of `NOLOCK` in `Mysql`:

```
 SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
 SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ;
 SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ ;
```

Refer [this](https://dbamohsin.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/nolock-equivalent-in-mysql/).

Comment: what exactly is wrong in my query. Earlier, i have used this query and it worked fine. What am i missing.